# Why isn't "Clean Solution" a choice on the "Build" menu for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, build

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.11.5) and am trying to get my application .dll and .pdb files to rebuild. This is an ASP.NET Web Application using the .NET Framework. Most solutions out there state that using "Clean Solution" will do it, but that choice is not available on the Build menu?

Comment: You might consider using clean/purge in your source control system if you have issues building. In my experience this is a bit more reliable.

Comment: I see a "Clean Solution" on my "Build" menu in VS 2019. Maybe somehow you removed it?

Comment: Have you opened the solution using the `.sln` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you only get that menu for a compiled project, or what we call a

```
asp.net web application
```

but, if you are using a

```
asp.net web site
```

Then you don't have a clean, and in fact the web site gets compiled on the fly by IIS and the web site - not Visual Studio.

So, if you using a asp.net web site application (and you should!!!), then you will see and get these options:

[image]

NOTE VERY VERY CAREFULL!!! - NO build web site!!!!!!!

However, if you open a web site, then you don't see those options. You see this:

[image]

Note in above - build web site. And note no clean application.

The "clean" option applies to both desktop, or web applications.

The difference?

Now, in most cases I MUCH prefer a web site application (but this makes single page code updates to the site MORE difficult, yet I still perfer that choice!!).

The list of differences between the two choices here are VERY long. But when you deploy, or run the application, then all pages (code behind) are taken and compiled down into a single application .dll (much like a desktop program). You also have MORE options such as being able to build and make a custom logon system (a custom authentication provider). And you have used a .sln (project file) to open this "applicaiton"

However, a LOT of people like using a asp.net web site. There are several reasons:

```
You can modify JUST one page + save and not have to re-compile the whole site.
You can publish to a sub site, or "low cost" hosting

Your main page, application startup is NOT really a whole site, 
but in effect just web pages being pushed up to a existing web site.
```

And even development is "easer" with a web site - you can modify one page (including code behind, hit ctrl-s to save, and you are done.

With a asp.net web application? You have to re-publish the WHOLE site again, even for a small one change to some code behind on a page.

So, as noted, did you open a "sln" file? = asp.net web site application

Or, did you just go open->open web site? = aspnet web site.

There is not going to be a "clean" option for asp.net web sites, since as noted, the IIS and web server will do the code compile for you, as opposed to a web site application, in which a set of .dll's are compiled into the bin file. (and in fact the main code behind gets compiled INTO ONE .dll with a "application"). As noted, with a application then publishing is more difficult, and you can't just update one page on the web site (code behind). With a asp.net web site, you can update the one page - and often some need or find this ability an advantage (I personally don't).

So to be really clear - a asp.net web site is NOT compiled by Visual Studio when run. With a asp.net web site application, the compile of the application occures first and THEN is passed to the IIS web server and then run - in that case, no on the fly compile of code occures, except for code app_code. So, as a result, I even use a foler called MyCode, since I don't want the web site to compile that code for me. (in fact, I had code break, since I started using vs2019 - and the newer "rosylyn editor - and it allow for example free strings such as sql statements in the code editor, but IIS can't compile them unless the web server .net compiler was upgraded to a later version).

Comment: I open a .sln file.

I open a .sln file for another application and the "Clean Solution" is available.

I have tried to look at the differences between the two and cannot see what the difference is.

Comment: As I stated, web sites don't have the clean solution option. (but they in general don't have   a sln file either - so that seems to be a issue we not resolved.  A sln file should not exist for a web site, but will for a web site application. However, regardless, it not at all surprising that you don't have clean solution - since that is normal and you will not see nor have that option when opening a web site. So, this issue will still depend on the type of project.  So either the sln file should not exist, or the web site was opened as a project, and not a web site.

Comment: For the most part, this answer worked. Because I am working with Visual Studio 2019 and a lot of stuff out there is based on much older versions, be very careful in which rabbit hole you enter. I found this link supremely helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/aa983476(v=vs.100)

The only "gotcha" here is when you get to "Convert to Web Application". Click on the root of your solution in Solution Explorer and then click on Project on the main menu bar and look ALL the way at the bottom of the Project submenu and you will see "Convert to Web Application".

Comment: No one suggesting to convert this to a web based application. You as a general rule can't change the whole architecture  in one simple choice here without MASSIVE ramifications. if that site been deployed as a web site, and NOT  web site application? Then no one in their right might would even try or suggest that you going to make such a earth shattering change to the application - you would ONLY do that if you 100% sure that the production web site, but MORE specific the web server in question can handle a web site applcation. As I stated, in a LOT of cases no you can't and should not change

Comment: but then again, if you have any basic knowledge and experience using asp.net, then the above would be Mr. Obvious, right? You often can't just change a web site over to run as a web site application. You probably can local, but you have to take into consideration the web server hosting this, and running IIS.  So, local, you not have any trouble or issue running the site as a web based application (as opposed to web site). But this massive elephant in the room certainly cannot be ignored at deployment time to the server running IIS.

Comment: This hasn't been deployed yet. I wasn't suggesting it would be easy to convert with the press of a button, just indicating that I found a way to get it done. It required some work but the result was what I was looking for.

Comment: no real huge issue. I just was pointing out why no clean project, and at least consider that the the existing hosting of the site may not well support or work with a web application. (it actually might - but this issue needs to be resolved before you put any time + effort into this, else you wind up with a site that can't be published to the existing hosting. Other then this issue? No worries. To be fair, it is a small difference, and a source of confusing for many.